# Open Mass Spec Database

Tags: database, ncbi, mass-spectrometry

Wondering if there is an *open* (freely available) database of [Mass Spec Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry_data_format), particularly for the Substances/Compounds listed in NCBI.

Specifically, I am not sure if NCBI includes the mass spectrometry data / datafiles in their FTP server related to any of their chemicals. So I am just wondering if there is an open database of mass spec datafiles out there somewhere.

Comment: It's unclear what you are looking for, there are many substances/compounds listed in NCBI. Could you clarify this so the question can be answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Human metabolome database (HMDB) contains many MS/MS and NMR spectra for human metabolites. You can acquire the spectra from the [downloads section](http://www.hmdb.ca/downloads). The HMDB includes external identifiers for each compound. This includes the PubChem Compound IDs that are given on the NCBI database. There are 2 265 compounds with LC-MS/MS spectra in the HMDB.

The **excellent** [MS-DIAL software package](http://prime.psc.riken.jp/Metabolomics_Software/MS-DIAL/) also comes with extensive positive and negative ion mode LC-MS/MS and GC-MS/MS spectral libraries in flat text format; that's also worth a look.

A lot of the raw spectral data is restricted due to multi party agreements (NIST, chemspider).